# Задача про ползущую улитку

Tags: pascal

Улитка ползёт по вертикальному шесту высотой `h` метров, поднимаясь за день на `a` метров, а за ночь спускаясь на `b` метров. На какой день улитка доползёт до вершины шеста?

Программа получает на вход натуральные числа `h, a, b` и должна вывести одно натуральное число. Гарантируется, что `a>b`.

***При решении этой задачи нельзя пользоваться условной инструкцией `if` и циклами.***

```
var h, a, b, c: integer;
begin
readln(h,a,b);
c:=(h div(a-b)-b);
writeln(c);
end.
```

Такое вот решение почему-то половину тестов не проходит :(
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задачку решить, последняя осталась :)

***Решение можно на C# или C++ написать.***

Answer (score 4):

А вот так решается?

```
int h,a,b,shag,h0;
cin>>h>>a>>b;
h0=h-a;
shag=a-b;
cout<<1+h0/shag+(h0%shag+shag-1)/shag;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, решается :)

Comment: @Infooter, не забудьте принять ответ.

Comment: Так, а теперь объясните пожалуйста смысл решения, ответы то  верные получаются, но я вот не понимаю самого решения :(

Answer (score 1):

Приведенное решение математически правильно, но осмыслить его логически едва ли возможно.
Суть задачи в том чтобы определить делится ли нацело общая длинна на расстояние пройденное за сутки или нет, если делится то h/(a-b) и будет ответом, если не делится то для получения верного ответа нужно прибавлять единицу отбрасывая дробную часть

(h-h%(a-b))/(a-b) + 1

Значит прибавляемое число зависит от результата целочисленного деления h%(a-b), поэтому достаточно преобразовать этот результат в единицу если он больше нуля или если он равен нулю то преобразование не должно влиять на результат. Это позволяет сделать следующая формула

|0^h%(a-b) - 1|

На C#:

System.out.println(Math.Truncate(h/(a-b)) + Math.Abs(Math.Pow(0, h%(a-b)) - 1));

или просто :)

System.out.println(Math.Ceiling(h/(a-b)));

Comment: "но осмыслить его логически едва ли возможно" почему это ? По моему, как раз Вы совершенно логично объясняете решение.

Comment: я имел ввиду вариант на срр

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int H, A, B;
    cin >> H >> A >> B;
    cout << (H / (A - B) - (A - (H % (A - B))) / (A - B)) + 1;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Желательно, дать пояснение каждой операции, объединённой по смыслу.

Answer (score 0):

А может так?

```
program aa;
uses math;
var h, a, b, c: integer;
begin
    ReadLn(h, a, b);
    Writeln('h=', h, ' a=', a, ' b=', b);
    WriteLn('Зверь достигнет вершины на ', Ceil(Max(0, h - a)/(a - b)) + 1, ' день');
end.
```

Считаем, что последний день улитке не надо спускаться, поскольку она уже наверху `h - a`,
этот остаток делим на подъём за день. Cлучаи `h < a` отсекаем функцией `max(0, h-a)`
Для случаев `(h-a)/(a-b)` -- нецелое, используем `ceil`, поскольку `(h-a)/(a-b) >= c-1`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int h, a, b, n=1, m;
cin >> h >> a >> b;
if (((h-a)%(a-b))>0) {
  m=++n;
   cout << m+(h-a)/(a-b);
  }
   else if (a>h) {
       cout << "1";
   }
  else {
   cout << n+(h-a)/(a-b);
  }
  }
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]